# Print Windows mapping of root path in MSYS Bash

Tags: bash, bash-scripting, msysgit, msys

In MSYS Bash I get:

```
$ cd ~             
$ pwd              
/c/Users/antonio
```

but:

```
$ cd / 
$ pwd              
/
```

Can I get the full Windows absolute path from Bash?

Answer (score 4):

In recent versions, e.g. [MSYS2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2/), you can use:

```
~$  cygpath -w /
C:\path\to\root
```

or with a mixed path style:

```
~$  cygpath -m /
C:/path/to/root
```

Similarly, you might use:

```
~$  cygpath -w ~
C:\path\to\home
~$  cygpath -m ~
C:/path/to/home
```